# How can I write to an HTML file from Python class

Tags: python, html

I am trying to write to an HTML file from my IDLE Python file. My task is to write all HTML code essentially as one string, using tags that I have made in my HTML object file. I am unsure of how to properly write my 'write()' method into my HTML file.

Here is my HTML object code:

```
from ReusableCustomerObject import customer
from Milestone2 import*

class HTMLwebpage:

    def __init__(self, st):
        self.st = st

    def htmlopen(self, st):
        self.f=open('HTMLMilestone3.html', 'w')

    def table(self, st):
        __table = "<table style='width: 100%;'; border='1'>"
        return table

    def tbody(self, st):
        __tbody = "<tbody>"
        __tbodyc = "</tbody>"
        return tbody + str(st) + tbodyc

    def tr(self, st):
        __tr = "<tr>"
        __trc = "</tr>"
        return tr + str(st) + trc

    def th(self, st):
        __th = "<th>"
        __thc = "</th>"
        return th + str(st) + thc

    def td(self, st):
        __td = "<td>"
        __tdc = "</td>"
        return td + str(st) + tdc

    def paragraph(self, st):
        __para = "<p>"
        __parac = "</p>"
        return para + str(st) + parac

    def h1(self, st):
        __h1 = "<h1>"
        __h1c = "</h1>"
        return h1 + str(st) + h1c

    def write(self, st):
        st = formatClient()
        return self.st.write(str(st))

fh = open('HTMLMilestone3', 'w')
fh.write(write(st))
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a string like the one bellow and send it to the html file you want to create/edit:

```
message = """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>Hello World!</p></body>
</html>"""
```

after you have done this with your class functions, you write the string you created to the file:

```
f = open('helloworld.html','w') # w if you want to write override or a if you want to write and append
f.write(message)
f.close()
```

in the end it's gonna look something like that:

```
from HTMLwebpage import *

message = htmlopen() + h1("Hello") + tr("the tr")
f = open('helloworld.html','w') # w if you want to write override or a if you want to write and append
f.write(message)
f.close()
```

Comment: But instead of having tags inside that string, how can I make use of the tags in the class?

Comment: You use them to create the string

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how?

Comment: I add a little demonstration of how to use. I tried to use your class but i couldn't find the proper dependents. If you have another question please ask.